# ¿Cómo actualizar los valores de una lista después de eliminar un elemento en c# MVC?

Tags: mvc, lista, razor

Estoy trabajando con **`c#`** en **`MVC`**, hago uso del `Razor` y tengo una clase que además de contar con ciertos valores, tiene listas con objetos de otras clases.

El problema es que cuando quiero eliminar uno de los elementos de las listas, me hace la eliminación en el controlador, pero al llegar a la vista me sigue mostrando el elemento que **"eliminé"** pero desaparece el último de la lista original.

Sería de mucha ayuda si pudieran brindarme alguna solución o orientación al problema.

El código del **controlador**:

```
if (accion.Equals("2")) //Eliminar gasto  directo
{
    if (!eliminado.Equals(""))
    {
        GastosDirectos gd = p.GastosDirectos.ElementAt(Convert.ToInt32(eliminado));
        p.GastosDirectos.Remove(gd);
    }
    else
    {
        ViewData["errorGastoDirecto"] = "No se ha seleccionado ningún gasto directo para su eliminación";
    }
}
return View(p);
```

Comment: Puedes por favor agregar tu código `html`